# Problem with enotez and \includeonly

Tags: compiling, include, endnotes, enotez

Compiling a latex document using `\includeonly` and the package enotez may result on a document with uncorrect end notes.

For instance, if my document (main.tex) includes chap1.tex and chap2.tex, each of them using end notes, when I compile the document including only the second file and then compile another time the document by including only the first file, I obtain a pdf document containing the content of chap1.tex but the end notes of chap2.tex (even if change the tex files). The only way to correct this is to compile once including everything.

Is there a way to automatically force the update of the endnotes?
Note that the problem disappears when using the endnotes package instead.

Thanks for the help!
Best, 
Mathieu

File main.tex:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{reset = true, list-heading = \section*{#1}}

\includeonly{chap1}
% \includeonly{chap2}

\begin{document}
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\end{document}
```

File chap1.tex

```
Chapter 1: Text text \endnote{End note of chapter 1!}. Text text Text text Text text
\printendnotes
```

File chap2.tex is similar to chap1.tex (but 2 instead of 1 in the text and note).

Compilation: `latexmk -pdf main.tex`

Comment: it's generally true of `\includeonly` that the aux file will not really have totally reliable data unless you occasionally run the whole document. It's a lightweight system to speed up drafts by only typesetting one part of the document, but the information about the other parts is by design old or missing.

Comment: Even with at least 5 runs of the whole document enotez stumbles over includeonly - i am working on it. It's a fault of the package (my opinion)....